# Access remote Oracle DB with Python

Tags: python, oracle, express, cx-oracle

I have been trying to access an Oracle database using Python in Visual Studio. As for now, of this database I know my username and password, id and port. Nothing more.

What I did up to now was:

- I have installed Oracle 11g Express Edition and set the ORACLE_HOME environmental variable to C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server
- Added cx_Oracle library
- wrote this piece of code

  ip='ipaddress'
  port=1521
  SID='xe'
  dsn_tns=cx_Oracle.makedsn(ip,port,SID)
  db = cx_Oracle.connect('username','password',dns_tns)

At the moment I keep getting this error:

*TNS-12505: TNS:listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor*

and cannot find a solution to it; reading online it seems it has something to do with the listener.ora but I couldnt find a working solution for me.

Here it is

**listner.ora**

```
SID_LIST_LISTENER =
  (SID_LIST =
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = PLSExtProc)
      (ORACLE_HOME = C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server)
      (PROGRAM = extproc)
    )
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = CLRExtProc)
      (ORACLE_HOME = C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server)
      (PROGRAM = extproc)
    )
  )

LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = gvd-server.GLITRE-NETT.local)(PORT = 1521))
    )
  )

DEFAULT_SERVICE_LISTENER = (XE)
```

And tnsnames.ora

```
XE =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = gvd-server.GLITRE-NETT.local)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = XE)
    )
  )

EXTPROC_CONNECTION_DATA =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SID = PLSExtProc)
      (PRESENTATION = RO)
    )
  )

ORACLR_CONNECTION_DATA = 
  (DESCRIPTION = 
    (ADDRESS_LIST = 
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1)) 
    ) 
    (CONNECT_DATA = 
      (SID = CLRExtProc) 
      (PRESENTATION = RO) 
    ) 
  )
```

I appreciate any help and thank you all in advance.
Have a great day!

Comment: What is the error message? Can you connect through sqlplus ?

Comment: Hei sorry I forgot to add it in the post. This is the error: TNS-12505: TNS:listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor:

The express edition of oracle 11g doesnt seem to have SQLplus? Am i mistaken?

Comment: Solved! Have found out that the remote server database uses their own service_name which was different from xe :) Tusen takk!

Comment: You are mistaken. sqlplus is the core oracle CLI tool for doing anything near the oracle database including XE.